# Can't add ToggleButton to custom Ribbon

Tags: xml, ms-office, ribbon, ribbonx

Using the excellent **Office RibbonX Editor**, I've created a custom tab for the Ribbon in Word. I used code like this to add existing commands to it:

```
        <button idMso="FileSave" />
        <button idMso="FileSaveAs" />
        <button idMso="Bold" />
```

The first two icons appear as desired, and they work correctly. But the "Bold" button does not appear, neither the icon nor the label.  I determined that this happens only for ToggleButtons such as "Bullets" or "Superscript".

Comment: That's likely because a toggle button should be <toggleButton

Comment: That did it! Put that in an Answer so I can Accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct term for a toggle button is

> ```
> <toggleButton
> ```

as can be seen in the following xml which rebuilds the Paragraph tab in Word after I've made the original not visible

```
<!-- Recreate the portions of the Paragraph tab that we actually need -->
            <group 
                id="Home.Paragraphs" 
                label="Paragraph" 
                getVisible="RibbonCallbacksForVisibility.getVisible" 
                insertBeforeMso="GroupEditing">

                <box 
                    id="Home.Paragraph.Status"
                    boxStyle="horizontal">
                    <buttonGroup 
                        id="Home.Paragraph.Alignment">
                        <toggleButton idMso="AlignLeft"/>
                        <toggleButton idMso="AlignCenter"/>
                        <toggleButton idMso="AlignRight"/>
                        <toggleButton idMso="AlignJustify"/>    
                    </buttonGroup>

                    <buttonGroup 
                        id="Home.Paragraph.Marks"
                        visible="true">
                        <toggleButton idMso="ParagraphMarks"/>
                    </buttonGroup>

                </box>

                <box 
                    id="ParagraphIndent"
                    boxStyle="horizontal">
                    <button idMso="IndentDecreaseWord"/>
                    <button idMso="IndentIncreaseWord"/>
                </box>

                <box 
                    id = "ParagraphOther"
                    boxStyle="horizontal">
                    <gallery idMso="LineSpacingGallery"/>
                    <button idMso="SortDialogClassic"/>
                </box>

                <dialogBoxLauncher>
                    <button idMso="ParagraphDialog"/>
                </dialogBoxLauncher>

            </group>
```

Comment: Either this is newbie XML, or Fernando Andreu *really* needs to put together a user's manual!  (I'd do it for free if I wasn't so broke.)

Comment: Hand rolled don't you know. By someone whose skill level is marginally better than incompetent.

Comment: That wasn't a comment on your coding! I meant that maybe everyone but me knows about "toggleButton"